# Need Help in conversion of time into seconds which can handle with hours and without hours in Golang

Tags: go, time

want to change time duration is seconds but don't want to give hours every time (hrs as optional)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
  t1 := "01:30"
  seconds, _ := ConvertTimeFormat(t1) // not working fine for this
  fmt.Println(seconds)

   t2 := "01:01:15"
   second, _ := ConvertTimeFormat(t2) // working fine for this
   fmt.Println(second)
}

func ConvertTimeFormat(st string) (int, error) {
    var h, m, s int
    n, err := fmt.Sscanf(st, "%d:%d:%d", &h, &m, &s)
    fmt.Print(n, err)
    if err != nil || n != 3 {
        return 0, err  
    }
    return h*3600 + m*60 + s, nil
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is buggy, since you always expect 3 values in the Scanf func.

Try to parse it another way, like:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    t1 := "01:30"
    seconds, _ := ConvertTimeFormat(t1) // not working fine for this
    fmt.Println(seconds)

    t2 := "01:01:15"
    second, _ := ConvertTimeFormat(t2) // working fine for this
    fmt.Println(second)
}

func ConvertTimeFormat(st string) (int, error) {
    var sh, sm, ss string
    parts := strings.Split(st, ":")
    switch len(parts) {
    case 2:
        sm = parts[0]
        ss = parts[1]
    case 3:
        sh = parts[0]
        sm = parts[1]
        ss = parts[2]
    default:
        return 0, errors.New("Invalid format")
    }

    var (
        h, m, s int
        err     error
    )
    if sh != "" {
        h, err = strconv.Atoi(sh)
        if err != nil {
            return 0, err
        }
    }
    m, err = strconv.Atoi(sm)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    s, err = strconv.Atoi(ss)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return h*3600 + m*60 + s, nil
}
```

[Go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/TbOSuD04mcm)

Another solution is to handle the error and try to parse it in the another format:

```
func ConvertTimeFormat(st string) (int, error) {
    var h, m, s int
    _, err := fmt.Sscanf(st, "%d:%d:%d", &h, &m, &s)
    fmt.Println(h, m, s, err)
    if err != nil {
        h, m, s = 0, 0, 0
        _, err = fmt.Sscanf(st, "%d:%d", &m, &s)
        if err != nil {
            return 0, err
        }
    }
    return h*3600 + m*60 + s, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split input string at ":" and reverse iterate.
Multiply fields by 1, 60 or 3600 as per position
Add to seconds

Code

```
var mult = []int{1, 60, 60 * 60}

func ConvertTimeFormat(timeStr string) (int, error) {
    var secs int
    slice := strings.Split(timeStr, ":")
    arrlen := len(slice)// Check length <=3 here

    for i := arrlen - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        elem, err := strconv.Atoi(slice[i])
        if err != nil {
            return -1, fmt.Errorf("error parsing [%s] in [%s]  [%v]",
                slice[i], timeStr, err)
        }

        secs += (elem * mult[arrlen-i-1])
    }
    return secs, nil
}
```

Erroneous strings `"", ":", ":20", "str:30, "::"` etc will be reported by `Atoi()`

**Edit:**

Could also use multiplier instead of array, would be extra multiplication operation.

```
func ConvertTimeFormat(timeStr string) (int, error) {
    multiplier := 1
    for i := arrlen - 1; i >= 0; i-- {
        ... 
        secs += (elem * multiplier)
        multiplier *= 60
    }
    return secs, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's more easier to understand and rewrite by yourself. using official package **time** .

```
    func main() {
        t1 := "01:30"
        backSeconds(t1)
    
        t2 := "01:01:15"
        backSeconds(t2)
    
// input:  01:30 ----deal:  01m30s ----result:  90
// input:  01:01:15 ----deal:  01h01m15s ----result:  3675
    }
    
    func backSeconds(str string) {
        deal := preDeal(str)
        parse, err := time.ParseDuration(deal)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        fmt.Println("input: ", str, "----deal: ", deal, "----result: ", parse.Seconds())
    }
    
    func preDeal(str string) string {
        list := strings.Split(str, ":")
        var build strings.Builder
        tType := []string{"s", "m", "h"}
        j := len(list) - 1
        for i := 0; i < len(list); i++ {
            build.WriteString(list[i] + tType[j-i])
        }
        return build.String()
    }
```